# Particles.js : limit number of particles

Tags: particles.js

I can't find if it is possible to limit the total number of particles.

Is there any way of doing this?

[Particles.js Github](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js)

Comment: The answer below by @NicolaZaltron works perfectly and should be the accepted answer. The answer you accepted is just a cop out of doing it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify particles.js (row 750) adding an additional check in the push function:

```
/* ---------- pJS functions - modes events ------------ */

  pJS.fn.modes.pushParticles = function(nb, pos){

    pJS.tmp.pushing = true;

    if(pJS.particles.array.length<140){
        for(var i = 0; i < nb; i++){
          pJS.particles.array.push(
            new pJS.fn.particle(
              pJS.particles.color,
              pJS.particles.opacity.value,
              {
                'x': pos ? pos.pos_x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w,
                'y': pos ? pos.pos_y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h
              }
            )
          )
          if(i == nb-1){
            if(!pJS.particles.move.enable){
              pJS.fn.particlesDraw();
            }
            pJS.tmp.pushing = false;
          }
        }
    }

  };
```

I used 140 as maximum number since it is a good value in order to not lose performance. Obviously you can modify it as needed.

Comment: This works perfectly and answers the question in full. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: alright, I changed my plans a year ago on how I wanted my implementation on the website to work so I no longer needed this and forgot to mark a correct answer, but i'll mark it as answer. If it works it should work for anyone needing this :)

Answer (score 2):

I added a little on @Nicola Zaltron's solution making it responsive to the screen size by making the limit of particles based on the screen width and by doing that on smaller screens it wont look bad and it wont effect the performance.

```
/* ---------- pJS functions - modes events ------------ */

pJS.fn.modes.pushParticles = function(nb, pos){

  pJS.tmp.pushing = true;

  var limitNumOfParticles = Math.floor(pJS.canvas.el.width / 20);

  if(pJS.particles.array.length < limitNumOfParticles){

    // console.log("limit: ", limitNumOfParticles);
    // console.log("array: ", pJS.particles.array.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < nb; i++){
      pJS.particles.array.push(
        new pJS.fn.particle(
          pJS.particles.color,
          pJS.particles.opacity.value,
          {
            'x': pos ? pos.pos_x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w,
            'y': pos ? pos.pos_y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h
          }
        )
      )
      if(i == nb-1){
        if(!pJS.particles.move.enable){
          pJS.fn.particlesDraw();
        }
        pJS.tmp.pushing = false;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This solution seems interesting, I'll steal it for using it here https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be(with **javascript**):

```
// Get total particles
let particles = window['pJSDom'][0].pJS.particles.array.length

// Here set limit value
if(particles == 25){
  // Get particles array
  let array = window['pJSDom'][0].pJS.particles.array
  // Remove (starting from zero) 16 particles starting from 5
  array.splice(5,15)
  // Set new particles array
  window['pJSDom'][0].pJS.particles.array = array
}
```

Comment: Or you can use a library that has this feature already coded https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no way to limit the number of particles onscreen, so I changed the properties of the onHover and onClick so it won't add other particles. Solved my problem...

## EDIT

This was previously marked as answer because at the time it solved my problem, but is not a proper answer.
No longer marked as answer, since apparently @Nicola Zaltron answer works !

Answer (score 0):

i've found a good solution!
This is the simple code:

> ```
> const maxParticles = 60;
> particlesJS.load('particles', './assets/particlesjs.json', () => {
>   const pJSIndex = 0;
>   const pJS = pJSDom[pJSIndex].pJS;
>   pJS.particles.array.splice(0, pJS.particles.array.length - maxParticles);
>   pJS.interactivity.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
>     pJS.particles.array.splice(0, pJS.particles.array.length - maxParticles);
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: Or you can migrate to a newer version with the native limit support like https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles

Answer (score -2):

When initialising particlesJS, change the value of number.value to limit number of particles

```
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": <change this to limit number of particles>,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
     ......
   }
```

See it in action : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggoRXy

Comment: This is the initial number of particles, it's not exactly what I was looking for. I'm looking for a maximum number of particles.